# How can i post a json object with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

im a beginner coder and i want to make a contact form sending a json object to another php file. This is my current code

```html
[...]
<body>
        <form id="form" class="formular">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="phone" type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="phone" required>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="mail" required>
            </div>
                <br>
            <div class="input-group">
                <textarea id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="message..." required></textarea>
            </div>
            <button id="form_submit_button" name="form_submit_button">Send!</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>


<?php
?>

<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#form_submit_button").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'test.php',
                data: JSON.stringify({ Form: $('#form').val }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
            })



        });
    });



</script>
```

The test.php simly is: var_dump($_POST);
Of course it's always 0. Can someone help me please :)

Comment: not realy, i don't understand how most of it works.... :/

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is to send the contents of the form using AJAX. As pointed out by NVRM, you don't need to use jQuery to do this. You can use the native fetch function.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');

form.onsubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
  const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  const message = document.getElementById('message').value;

  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('phone', phone);
  data.append('email', email);
  data.append('message', message);
  
  fetch("test.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data
  });
}
```

```html
<form id="form" class="formular">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="phone" type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="phone" required>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="mail" required>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="input-group">
    <textarea id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="message..." required></textarea>
  </div>
  <button id="form_submit_button" name="form_submit_button">Send!</button>
</form>
```

First, you put the values of each of the form fields into variables, and then insert them into a `FormData` object. Then use the `fetch` function to send the `FormData` object to the server where it can be accessed from the `$_POST` variable.

What you had originally was `$('#form').val()` which doesn't return anything because `#form` is the form element, which doesn't have a value.

Answer (score -1):

Try instead `$('#form').serialize()`.
You may also use FormData.

Answer (score -1):

You are not forced to use jquery, here is a possible way using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) native javascript.

```js
document.getElementById("form_submit_button").onmousedown = () => {
  fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({"phone": phone.value, "email": email.value, "message": message.value})
  }).then(a=>a.json())
    .then(a => console.log(a))
}
```

```html
<form id="form" class="formular">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="phone" value="555777">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="email" id="email" value="lol@gov.com">
            </div>
                <br>
            <div class="input-group">
                <textarea id="message">
                Message in textarea 
                </textarea>
            </div>
           
</form>

<button id="form_submit_button">Send!</button>
```